# Thread.Interrupt() does not work and I don't really see reason why

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Like I am very upset because I do not understand why it does not work.

Here is part of my code:

```
if (!loadThread.isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it gives me error:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.InterruptedException
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:442)
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:358)
    at me.igor.comunicator.client.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:94)
```

And line 94 Is `Thread.sleep(500);`. And it is very weird because If it gives my error that Thread is interrupted so why does `if(!loadThread.isInterrupted()) {` get executed as true?

Comment: So you check before the sleep, and what is preventing something from interrupting the thread during your sleep?

Comment: Are those the same thread or two different threads? A [mre], please?

Comment: The same @OleV.V.

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to understand what interrupt does or how it works.

A short tutorial:

- Checking the state of *other* thread's interrupted flag is exceedingly weird. **It is likely you wanted `Thread.interrupted()` instead of `loadThread.isInterrupted()`**.
- When you set the interrupt flag on a thread, nothing happens immediately. We're not waiting around for something that reads the flag to run in that thread, at which point something will happen. There are only 2 interactions with that flag:

  1. is calling `Thread.interrupted`. If you call that method when your thread's interrupt flag is raised, that will return `true`, **and will lower the flag**.
  2. is calling any method that has a specific interaction with that flag. **Every** method that is specified to `throws InterruptedException`, such as `Thread.sleep`, is guaranteed to interact with it: These methods will throw `InterruptedException` **and lower the flag**. If the flag is up when you invoke the method, they return **immediately** by lowering the flag and throwing the exception. Methods that aren't specced to throw InterruptedEx, but which do 'sleep', such as `fileInputStream.read()`, may or may not interact with it: JVM's choice. Depends on your OS. If they interact with it, they'll lower the flag and throw e.g. `IOException`. They won't (and can't) throw `InterruptedException`.

That means a few things for your code:

1. Of course your `isInterrupted()` call returns false: It hasn't interrupted *YET*, that happens during those 500 milliseconds.
2. In general you don't **need** the check, at all. **The only way to deal with interupts here is to catch that exception**. There is simply no other way. That will also take care of all possible occurences, you don't need any check. This is the code you must write, and it covers all relevant cases:

```
boolean wasInterrupted;
try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    wasInterrupted = false;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    wasInterrupted = true;
}

if (wasInterrupted) {
   // do whatever you intended to do here
}
```

The reason you don't need to call `Thread.interrupted` at all is because `Thread.sleep` will do it for you at no cost (performance or otherwise).

Note that threads **never get interrupted by anything**, except you specifically writing `someThread.interupt()`. e.g. the user pressing CTRL+C or going into their task manager or activity monitor or whatnot and ending your process, forcefully or not, **does not** cause interrupts.

Comment: `Thread.interrupted()` is not recommended because it unsets the interrupted flag.  `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is what should be used.  The OP's use of `isInterrupted()` is correct.

Comment: Also, there are many other places which cause a thread to be interrupted without the programmer directly calling `somethread.interrupt()`.  `threadPool.shutdownNow()` comes to mind.  I understand your point but it could be misinterpretted.

Comment: @Gray No, you're wrong: Clearing the flag is part of the point. The 'flow' of how to use the interrupt API is designed around clearing that flag once you act on it.

Comment: Yeah no.  It's usually not recommended.  If you clear the flag then the caller will have no idea that the current thread is interrupted.  It's why we reinterrupt the thread when we catch InterruptedException.  You typically want to test the interrupt status without clearing and you want to reinterrupt once you catch InterruptedException.

Comment: _It's usually not recommended_ - Appeal to.. what? It's a logical fallacy in any case. Or, as wikipedians would say it, [citation needed]. But, hey, if appeals are fair game: I'll just say that it is usually recommended. I will even, unlike you, pull in one source for this claim other than myself: The designers of the API itself, which didn't add 'lower that flag' for giggles. They think it the API works better that way.

Comment: Yeah sorry.  Should have provided refs: https://newbedev.com/why-invoke-thread-currentthread-interrupt-in-a-catch-interruptexception-block https://myshadesofgray.wordpress.com/2014/04/13/and-you-thought-you-knew-java-multithreading/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622554/best-practices-for-handling-interruptedexception https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-the-interruptedexception

Comment: The designers also added `thread.stop()` which was a tremendously bad idea.  Just because the API has a method doesn't mean it is recommended that it be used.  There are certainly times where `Thread.interrupted()` is fine but the problem with SO answers is that they can propagate bad patterns even if they make sense in the context of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if(!loadThread.isInterrupted()) {
> ```

So the answer depends on whether or not `loadThread` is the current running thread or  another thread running in your application.  Since you are in the `MainActivity`, the current running thread may be the main thread and the `loadThread` is some background load thread that the current thread is checking the status of.

If `loadThread` is the current thread then there really isn't any point in testing the interrupt flag.  The `Thread.sleep()` will throw  immediately if the flag is set.

> ```
> W/System.err: java.lang.InterruptedException
> ```

This is saying that the current running thread has been interrupted.  You can see by the stack trace that the thread was in `Thread.sleep(...)` when it threw.  This may or may not have anything to do with `loadThread`.

> why does `if(!loadThread.isInterrupted()) {` gets executed as true.

So if the `loadThread` is the current running thread then it is very possible that it tests its interrupt status and then calls `Thread.sleep()`.  While it is sleeping is when the interrupt gets delivered.  I assume this code is in some sort of test loop?  The chances of the code getting interrupted *outside* of the sleep may be actually pretty small.  This is classic race condition so the interrupt could be delivered before the `isInterrupted()` or after during the sleep – the code has to be prepared for either possibility.

Lastly, in most situations it is recommended that you re-interrupt a thread when you catch `InterruptedException`.  The reason is that when `InterruptedException` is thrown, the interrupt status of the thread is cleared.  If you exit the routine, you want the calling code to be able to also test the interrupted flag – you don't want to clear it artificially.  There are 3rd party libraries that catch and don't re-interrupt the thread which can cause major problems in threaded applications.

```
try {
   Thread.sleep(500);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   // immediately re-interrupt the thread so callers can test it too
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   // deal with the interrupt which typically means exiting the the thread
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is interrupted during waiting (executing `Thread.sleep` instruction)
In that case `InterruptedException` is thrown.

In your code there is nothing else than Thread.sleep. So it is very little chance that thread running this code will be interrupted after thread.sleep, but before if.isInteruppted.

Your program should not fail - just print stacktrace and go on with exectution (code after `try` block). In this case it is appropriate to just `log.debug` when `InterruptedException`  is catch (it is not error).

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long) for details

Comment: In most cases it's considered bad form to just continue after catching InterruptedException. Your thread is being interrupted and you typically should have it exit or return. In some situations applications use the interrupt flag to cause a thread to stop sleeping so that it can check something and continue but that logic is less typical.